# Is it ethical for Albert Einstein to get lecture notes of Geometry class from his personal friend rather than taking the class himself?

Tags: ethics

In http://www.cvastro.org/ECP1.pdf page 8,

> Fortunately his friend, Marcel Grossman attended class regularly and
>   took notes which he carefully rewrote. Grossman allowed Einstein to
>   use his notes to prepare for the final exams which he subsequently
>   passed. This is the first instance of Grossman coming to Einstein's
>   rescue.

Albert Einstein got lecture notes of Geometry (not sure if this is exactly geometry) classes from his personal friend rather than taking the class himself. Since he did not attend the class himself and take the notes himself, I feel that he was in an advantage compared to students attending the class and taking the notes themselves.

Not being an ethical hypocrite but I just feel this is unfair (A question comes from sympathy to his classmates in fact.). Personally, sometimes I feel too tired, or the professors bad at teaching but their notes are important (Sometimes one trick the professors ensure high attendance is to suddenly talk about exam questions in class.), or have time clash in the class, I wish I can get notes from someone rather than attending the class or just attending, concentrating on listening but not taking notes. But I feel that this is unethical as many students have the same problems. So if I do so, I have a "time advantage" compared to them.

Comment: So you claim that the _only_ source of knowledge should come from inside the class and nowhere else? _Even_ if it is an advantage (which is highly debatable) what is the point? You also have advantage for attending a university in comparison to other students that they do not even have that advantage.

Comment: This depends on the requirements for the course.  If passing the course is based only on the exam, then attending the class is not necessary.  Non-attendence is not an ethical lapse.  But, for most students, non-attendence is merely stupid--since, not having Einsteins intellect,  they will fail the exam.

Comment: Why would it be unfair? He had to pass the same exam as all others.

Comment: @GEdgar but it is not attending but getting class notes.

Comment: Don't forget that the point in taking a course is learning.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt but there are some courses I do not want to learn, having time clash with the course I want to learn, but I am forced to take them and pass the exam within a fixed timeframe.

Comment: @kyle in that case, in my opinion, do whatever it takes to minimize the time cost.

Comment: Even more amazing: for most courses there's a book that you could just read on your own to learn the same material, and more. ("... education you could have got for a dollar fifty in late charges at the public library!")

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any ethical problem here.  If you don't want to attend class, you are under no ethical obligation to do so.  (Of course, if attendance is required, you may suffer a grade penalty.)

And if another student is willing to share their notes with you, they are free to do so, and you are free to read them (unless of course the professor or your institution's regulations have forbidden this).

If you truly believe your education would be improved by skipping class and reading notes from a classmate instead, ethics permits you to do so.

However, it's my considered opinion that the vast majority of students who think this is to their benefit are wrong.  Reading notes taken by someone else is not the same as attending the lecture and taking your own notes.  You are at the mercy of your classmate's errors and omissions.  And you miss out on the opportunity to ask questions of the lecturer, participate in class discussions, et cetera.